# multer cant upload file with storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to upload an image file using multer but when I configure it with storage it doesn't save the file

when i use with normal parameter it works fine
`const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploadAvatar' })`

but as such the file has no extension (like .png,...)
so I am trying to configure it with storage but when running the file is not saved and the destination directory is not generated
(I tried the awd file parameter in both functions and it still recognizes the file)

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
        console.log(file)//I've got the files here
        callback(null, 'uploads/')
    },
    filename: (req, file, callback) => {
        console.log(file) //I've got the files here
        const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix)
    }
})
const upload = multer({ storage: storage })
Rounter.post('/create-user-admin', upload.single('avatar'),
        (req, res) => {
            console.log('test')//this don't work too
        }
    )
```

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a dot in your destination so that the uploads folder is created relative to your current working directory.

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
        console.log(file)//I've got the files here
        callback(null, './uploads')
    },
    filename: (req, file, callback) => {
        console.log(file) //I've got the files here
        const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix)
    }
})
```

Comment: After double check it's true that it's related to the directory not found. Your answer is very helpful,thank you